# Custom connector action webhook error handling

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

We are currently implementing a `custom connector` to retrieve data from a  legacy system.
Since these queries take a long time we use the `ApiConnectionWebhook` pattern for actions.

> like described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/connectors/custom-connectors/create-webhook-trigger

The "happy path" works great. But now we are facing the challenge to handle technical and logical errors in these queries.
The Logic Apps Engine generates the callback url when registering an action webhook via `@{listCallbackUrl()}`.

Is there any way to report an error status to the engine during the callback (call of the url)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is no dedicated error callback URL, you could instead POST a more verbose response like below

```
{
   "status": "Success", // Or "Fail" / "Error"
   "data": "<actual-response>" // Or error message as required
}
```

And after the webhook action, you could check the status value using a [switch action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-switch-statement) and have an optional parallel path based on the value.